# TFS - 'Run Functional Test' Task doesn't show machine group

Tags: c#, tfs, selenium-chromedriver

Right now I'm trying to run a selenium test in TFS (Team Foundation Server), as a first option I tried to use 'Visual Studio Test' Task but i got the follow error:

"System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'WebDriver, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF."

I guess it´s because this Task can´t resolve the webDriver dll( the dll is referenced and in TFS code there's the dlls ), so i tried to use  'Run functional Test' but the problem in here is that doesn't letme choose the machine group that, of course, I've all ready set, so, what should I do?

The task 'Visual Studio Test' can be use for selenium tests? Why can't I add the machine group??

[This is How the setting for 'Run Functional Test' appears to me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nWSFD.png)

[Config for 'Visual Studio Test Agent Deployment' TASK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nggG5.png)

[Error for 'Visual Studio Test Agent Deployment' TASK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jfVbg.png)

Comment: What version of TFS are you using?

Comment: my TFS  is 2015, version 14.95.25229.0, there's any bug in this version for 'run functional task' task ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Visual Studio Test` **version 2** supports run unit and functional tests (Selenium, Appium, Coded UI test, etc.). Test frameworks that have a Visual Studio test adapter such as xUnit, NUnit, Chutzpah, etc. can also be run. Visual Studio Test **version 2** exists in TFS 2017 and later versions.

You can still use `Run Functional Tests` task and it’s companion task (`Visual Studio Test Agent Deployment`). But you have to type the machine name manually as there is not selection option in current TFS versions. Here is a screenshot of TFS 2015:

[image]

Useful links:

- https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/VsTest/README.md
- https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2017/03/26/vstest-task-dons-a-new-avatar-testing-with-unified-agents-and-phases/

Comment: well I've tried that before but doesn't let me write anything, just the combo box to choose the machine group.
Can I install the 'Visual Studio Test'V2 in TFS 2015? or it's just available for TFS2017 ??

Comment: I just Add a link in the main Q with the image to show how it looks for me the same Setup Options

Comment: I updated to the 4.1 , but I'm having some troubles with my Build agent there's any direct download of the build agent for this upload?? the changes in the tasks can be seen , but a can't make the tests in order to confirm the solution , as i told you so far the update let me set the "Group Machines".

Comment: I solve that Build Agent Problem, but now I got this msj in (Visual Studio Test Agent Deployment): (Visual Studio Test Agent Deployment)

Comment: Error occured on '***:5985'. Details : 'Failed to install 'VisualStudioRemoteDeployerb594cb1c-9635-4e57-8eda-d89c3cb29f53' from service executable path VisualStudioRemoteDeployer.exe . Consult the logs below:
Exception calling "SetRight" with "2" argument(s): "Could not obtain the user information."
CategoryInfo :NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
FullyQualifiedErrorId :Exception
'. For troubleshooting, refer http://aka.ms/remotevstest. I'm admin of this machine, Where should I set de Agent setting to put in this Task?

Comment: The error complained "Could not obtain the user information", did you specify the machine username and password?

Comment: Yes I did, which permission should I give to this user in order to let it run the agent?

Comment: Could you share a screenshot of your build definition?

Comment: I just added another two links in the main Q

Comment: Username should be an admin on the Test Machines on which Test Agent is being deployed. You can try to type `domain\username` directly instead of variables to see how's the result.

Comment: TY @CeceDong sorry I'm answering this late I was traveling, everything works perfect now.